# Set default value in number picker return java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, numbers, picker

When I set dafault value 20 error return java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=-1. If set default value 30 is not have problem why?

```
    NumberPicker numberPicker=inflated.findViewById(R.id.number_picker);
    final String[] pickerValues = new String[] {"20", "30", "40", "50","60"};
    numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(pickerValues);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(pickerValues.length-1);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setValue(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `maxValue` to `length-1` (it is 5-1=**4**) and then you set `value` to 20. Of course 20 is out of bounds. You can set a value between **0 and 4**. `setValue(int index)` function doesnt set parameter to picker. It sets index of array. So it gets value from array you passed to picker matching to index parameter.